# How to ensure sending a .ICS file on Gmail will result in an "add to calendar"

Tags: gmail, google-calendar

I have noticed that sometimes, when I receive a calendar invite (.ICS file) I do not get an *add to calendar* option in my Gmail read view.

[image: Notice no <code>add to calendar</code> option]

Notice no *add to calendar* option.

Other times I do get this:

[image: Notice the <code>add to calendar</code> option is there]

Here we do have the option.

So, when sending an email, how do I ensure Gmail detects the calendar .ICS file is attached and offers the user an *add to calendar* option?

Answer (score 1):

When I had this problem, I just needed to pop over to [old Gmail](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?nocheckbrowser) and I saw the Add To Calendar link.